# Automatically replace assignment operator with "set" function

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt

I'm porting my C++ Windows-project built with Embarcadero RAD Studio to Linux with Qt.
So I have many statements in my code like that:

```
Menu->Enabled = true;
```

For Qt it should be transformed like that:

```
Menu->setEnabled(true);
```

So now I'm losing a lot of time commenting code. Is there a way to do this replacement automatically?

Comment: Well, i won't actually answer your question, but overusing setters are generally bad. If there is a public member, like here the enabled, you shouldn't write a setter for it unless it do something more than giving the new value for it. (like checking if it's a valid new value) To be honest, setter can help you in debugging, so it can be useful, but for a logically public member i don't like it.

Comment: Well written regex substitution is the simplest solution which will do the work. I would not recommend you use macros (if it's even possible).

Comment: @Melkon One more moment is that "Enabled" property in Embarcadero was public, but in Qt it's private, so its value can be set only using setEnabled() function. Funcions like this is used rather often in my code for dynamically changing properties of user interface.

Comment: @vim do you mean that I should interpret source file like text and make substitution with some external tool? This method has one drawback that after this source cannot be used in Windows.

Comment: Write a wrapper class, with different implementations for Qt/whatever else you need that is incompatible with Qt.

Comment: @juanchopanza setEnabled() is owned by many QWidget-based classes of Qt so it's to be tedious to write wrappers for all of them.

Comment: I would use compilation directives. In the Borland times, one had the `__BORLANDC__` macro defined. You could use `#ifded  #ifdef __BORLANDC__`, `#else`, and `#endif` clauses around the code related to the portions you want to modify according to the platform. I guess that Embarcadero has kept this macro or defined a new version of it. From the top of my mind, such a directive was a bit trickier in QT. A google search suggests to use the macro `QT_VERSION`.

Comment: @rpsml I suggest it's the same as commenting code in each appearance of windows-related operators but in this case you make the code cross-platfrom.

Comment: You shoudln't presuppose a solution in your question. This is C++, macros would be an ugly crutch.

Comment: @Kuba Ober got it: made edits

Comment: The title still begins with the word "Macros".

Comment: @juanchopanza, writing a wrapper class won't catch plain data member assignments with setter code.  
Some surrogate class will let you use operator= but each field would need a pointer back to the enclosing object.  Still doable though; all the changes are to the constructor only.

Answer (score 3):

If this is some minor porting detail, that's getting in the way of more important issues to deal with, in this porting project, you can also consider postponing this refactoring until later, using an approach that goes something like this:

```
class Menu {

public:

      class punt_enabled {
          Menu *me;
      public:
          punt_enabled(Menu *meArg);
          Menu &operator=(bool flag);
      };

      punt_enabled Enabled;

 // ...

 };

 // ...

 Menu::Menu(...) : Enabled(this) //...

 Menu::punt_enabled::punt_enabled(Menu *meArg) : me(meArg) {}

 Menu &Menu::punt_enabled(bool flag) { me->setEnabled(flag); return *me; }

 // ...
```

This will let the compiler pinch hit and make this replacement on the fly, for now, and then you can come back and finish the job, using grep+sed, or perl, to handle wholesale replacement.

P.S. punt_enabled needs to be initialized by all constructors, including the copy and move constructors, of course.

Comment: Won't you need to hack or override Qt to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Whether you're in Linux OS or you've installed MinGW or Cygwin in Windows, to run Unix commands, execute the line below in your base folder where you'd want to change the code:

```
grep -rl "Menu->Enabled = true;" ./ | xargs sed -i "s/Menu->Enabled = true;/Menu->setEnabled(true);/g"
```

**Note**: this command works in all the files saved in the base folder and subfolders

**Edit**: execute the below command to apply to all the variables which are using "->Enabled = true" format or similar:

```
grep -rl -e "->Enabled = true;" ./ | xargs sed -i "s/->Enabled = true;/->setEnabled(true);/g"
```

Comment: What if every variable is not called Menu, or formatting is different, or contains expressions for the right-hand-side?

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would jump in and make the change, channeling some OCD until the build is clean.
To help with that approach, here are some tips:

First, change the name of the member rather than just making it private.  Make the name a unique token in the code, at least for the time being (you can do a dumb global replace later to name it what you wanted).

Second, many such lines have exactly the same formatting and even identical variable names, as they are written by people with uniform conventions or even copied from other occurrences.  That means that a series of dumb search/replace commands will find many occurrences each.  Locate one such line that needs changing, and issue a global replace across all files that matches the interesting part of it.  It does not need to be completely general as you will repeat with the next variation that still exists.  What about false hits?  Finding every field with that name even among other classes — if that's common, so what?  Add a setXXX member function to that class, too, that works the same as the public field.  Now replacements are harmless and it might inspire further encapsulating as well.

Third, use a local git branch and check in changes after every bulk operation.  That makes it easy to undo or repair later, or just to go back and look at what it said before.

If that's not a smart pointer but a primitive pointer, the Source Insight editor might do a smart rename of the field properly, mostly.  Then bulk change the new unique name with the function call using a regex.

Finally, you might check to see if compiler extensions are available as with Microsoft's that will implement property functions automatically.

But, you wanted some way to make the existing syntax work (or otherwise be fully automatic and correct).  So here's the idea:  use a surrogate class that has an operator= defined on it.  Something like this:

```
class C {
public:
   // int value;  -- OLD
   magic_int value;  // NEW
   ⋮
};
```

The constructors of C need to initialize all the `magic` fields with a pointer to the enclosing class, as C++ doesn't have automatic “inner classes” like Java.  So

```
C::C (whatever-it-did-before)
: existing-stuff,
   value(this,&C::setter)  // for each newly magic field
```

Now you want the semantics of assignment on the field to call the setter.  So we have something like:

```
int magic_int::operator= (int x)
{
(owner->*setfunc)(x);
}
```

This means that magic_int needs member data for owner and setfunc, as seen in the constructor.  Making it a template means employing the CRTP and giving it both the outer class type as well as the field's type:

```
template<typename OwnerT, typename ValueT>
class magic {
   friend class OwnerT;
   ValueT value;  // the real backing storage, if any.
   OwnerT* owner;
   void (OwnerT::setfunc(const ValueT&));
   ⋮      
};
```

Now this is arranged so that the nominated member function of C, the setter, can do whatever it needs to coordinate the setting, and as part of that it directly sets the primitive backing value.  The backing value is stored in the magic wrapper to simplify the dumb getter which is the implicit conversion operator.

Also, to get fancier, the set code selection could be done through a template argument, so the magic wrapper does not need to store an actual setfunc value in the instance.  That will cut an large data overhead (pointers to members are large) and also allow the operator= call to inline the real call at compile time.

Have fun.

Comment: It will take some time to get inside this idea :)

Comment: The same idea has been used to allow another operation such as operator[] to seemingly "know" if it's going to be used as a read or a write.  I've used it to support easy use of nested collections that create the intermediate levels only if you actually create the item by assigning to it, rather than just checking to see if it exists or reading a default value.

Let me know if you need any more discussion to grok it.  :)  First understand the proxy class (see std::vector<bool> for a similar use) itself, then the guts of this particular magic{}, then the way to make it a template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Qt Creator find and replace tools to automatically replace a specific pattern all over the project. Press `Ctrl+Shift+F` or select `Edit > Find/Replace > Advanced Find > Open Advanced Find`.
Select the scope of your search and press `Search & Replace` button. Then you can specify a text for replacement.

An other option is to press  `Ctrl+Shift+R` on a selected phrase and enter the replacement string.